# searchview. Suggestion list handle scroll

Tags: android, searchview

I have searchview in fragment. When I input some text, then show suggestion list with filter result. I can scroll this suggestion list. OK. Is it possible to handle scrolling of suggestion list?

Comment: May I know what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve is item in suggestion list is visible

Comment: And how many items show in suggestion list